# Map and return a new object instead of deleting existing data recursively

Tags: javascript

I have the following logic which goes in and switches all nested Object keys to camel case.

It works fine but I am currently deleting existing data in the object I am converting from.

Is there a way I could have mapped this instead and return a new object without affecting 
the initial object?

This is the working one where I am modifying the object being passed.

```
const convert = (data, caseType) => {
  Object.keys(data).forEach((previousKey) => {
    let newKey = case(previousKey);
    if (newKey !== previousKey) {
      data[newKey] = data[previousKey];
      delete data[previousKey];
    }

    if (typeof (data[newKey]) === 'object' || data[newKey] === Array) {
      data[newKey] = convert(data[newKey]);
    }
  });
  return data;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the entries, `map` to create your new structure, and then build the new object using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), like this:

```
const convertAllObjectKeyCase = (data, caseType) => {
    if (typeof data !== "object" || data === null) return data;
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(data).map(([previousKey, value]) => {
            let newKey;
            switch (caseType) {
                case SNAKE_CASE:
                    newKey = snakeCase(previousKey);
                    break;
                default:
                    newKey = camelCase(previousKey);
                    break;
            }
            // This condition looks suspect to me −−−vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            if (typeof value === "object" ||         value === Array) {
                value = convertAllObjectKeyCase(value);
            }
            return [newKey, value];
        })
    );
};
```

Or use a `for-in` loop and build the new object as you go:

```
const convertAllObjectKeyCase = (data, caseType) => {
    if (typeof data !== "object" || data === null) return data;
    const result = {};
    for (const previousKey in data) {
        // This matches with your previous use of `Object.keys`, which
        // skips inherited properties
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, previousKey)) {
            continue;
        }
        let value = data[previousKey];
        let newKey;
        switch (caseType) {
            case SNAKE_CASE:
                newKey = snakeCase(previousKey);
                break;
            default:
                newKey = camelCase(previousKey);
                break;
        }
        // This condition looks suspect to me −−vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        if (typeof value === "object" ||         value === Array) {
            value = convertAllObjectKeyCase(value);
        }
        result[newKey] = value;
    }
    return result;
};
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> 'This condition looks suspect to me'. i am checking if the value is another array or obj, get into there too to switch case for those nested ones.

x === Array checks to see if x is the Array constructor function, not if it's an array. If you want to handle arrays, you'll want to change that to Array.isArray(x) and change the logic of the function to handle arrays (since currently it assumes everything is a non-array object).

In both of the previous examples, to handle arrays, you can change this:

```
// This condition looks suspect to me −−−vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
if (typeof value === "object" ||         value === Array) {
    value = convertAllObjectKeyCase(value);
}
```

to this:

```
if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
    value = convertAllObjectKeyCase(value);
} else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    // Convert any objects in the array
    value = value.map(convertAllObjectKeyCase);
}
```

Or to avoid having the same logic in two places, just rely on the fact that `convertAllObjectKeyCase` checks for objects:

```
value = Array.isArray(value)
    ? value.map(convertAllObjectKeyCase)
    : convertAllObjectKeyCase(value);
```

Or even have `convertAllObjectKeyCase` handle arrays as well as objects by changing it to just:

```
value = convertAllObjectKeyCase(value);
```

and adding this just after the object/null check at the beginning:

```
if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.map(convertAllObjectKeyCase);
}
```

Comment: 'This condition looks suspect to me'. i am checking if the value is another array or obj, get into there too to switch case for those nested ones.

Comment: @karvai - `x === Array` checks to see if `x` is the `Array` constructor function, not if it's an array. If you want to handle arrays, you'll want to change that to `Array.isArray(x)` **and** change the logic of the function to handle arrays (since currently it assumes everything is a non-array object).

Comment: @karvai - I've added some options for how you might handle arrays in the object.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer. Trying to go with the for in loop option. All test cases passing but one where I am looping over this method so I can handle a list of objects too. Having a look on what am doing wrong. Added what I modified to and the related test case above if you have time. Thank you.

Comment: @karvai - Your list function is using `forEach`, which won't save the result of calling `convertAllObjectKeyCase` anywhere and which always returns `undefined` (so your `list` will be `undefined` after the `forEach` finishes). Use `map` as I showed at the end of the answer above.